Setting width for TRANSPARENT Stage -> gtk_window_resize: assertion 'height > 0' failed
I am trying to use transparent Stage. However, I can't set its width/height. When I set the width I get error about height, and if I try to set the height I get error about width.
This is my code
public class Test11 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        var button = new Button("Test");
        button.setOnAction(e -> primaryStage.setWidth(primaryStage.getWidth() - 10));
        var vBox = new VBox(button);
        vBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
        var scene = new Scene(vBox, 400, 300);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

And if you click the button you will get
(java:61615): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 20:46:53.565: gtk_window_resize: assertion 'height > 0' failed

I use JavaFX 23, Java 22.0.1, Ubuntu 20.04. Could anyone say if it is a bug or I am doing something wrong?

Looks like a bug. What does primaryStage().getHeight() return in the event handler?

@James_D It returns 300.0

@James_D Yes, it is a bug. The error appears in JavaFX 21, but not in JavaFX 20

Consider submitting a bug report, assuming one doesn't already exist for this bug.
